# How can I disable the click sound when an Android/Java listview item is tapped?

Tags: java, android, listview

How can I disable the click sound when a listview item is tapped ?

PS: I have android 2.3.4 and create the listview with Java.

Edit: I solved it by adding:

```
android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
```

to the xml of the listview layout.

Comment: People should leave comments when they down vote so the OP knows what they have to improve

Comment: I guess thats something they need to improve with their manners. :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you're looking for is [android:soundEffectsEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:soundEffectsEnabled) which can be set in the xml-document with

```
android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
```

or directly in java code with the corresponding

`setSoundEffectsEnabled(boolean)` method.

Comment: Or android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" in XML.